# AngularJS jQuery include old project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a very large project written with jQuery. Now I'm using AngularJS, but I need to load (possibly in a `div` tag) my old project. It seems to use `ng-include`, but my old project includes many scripts and some JS code generated by PHP. So using `ng-include` isn't helpful because the JS code inside this `old-project.php` doesn't work. Is there any way to open my `old-project.php` in a div in my AngularJS app?

Comment: Worst case could load it in an iframe. There is no simple answer without knowing a lot more detail

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately I think that iframe is the only way to solve my problem, but was hoping that there is some other way to do this.

Comment: Alternative is you would most likely need to convert the jQuery to be called inside directives instead of `document.ready`

Comment: I don't know! sorry

Answer (score 0):

Adding ng-include would include your project inside the angular js framework like a partial view so jquery script wont work inside angularjs framework. Using iframe would add your project as an seperate frame so that wont affect the framework and also your scripts inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow four steps:

Step 1: Create simple html page. Ex: `new.html` .

Step 2: You need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files.

Step 3: in 'new.html' file include this within php tag :

```
include '<old-project>.php';
```

Step 4: Now you can add 'new.html' file with `<ng-include>` .

Comment: but js script's wich my old-project.php include won't be working